# moving a key value pair out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to move everything in the Array Results outside and into the original object

this is the object

```
{
  "Name": "John",
  "Results": [
    {
      "Type": "DB",
      "Immediate_Action": "No",
    }
  ]
}
```

It should look like this

```
{
  "Name": "John",
  "Type": "DB",
  "Immediate_Action": "No",
}
```

What I have so far is this

```
const mapOscarResults = ({ data }) => {
    return data.map(entry => {
        let mapped = {...entry};
        entry.Results.forEach(key => {
            let Type =  mapped[key.Type]

            if (mapped[key]) {
                mapped[key].push(entry.Results[key]);
            } else {
                mapped[key] = [entry.Results[key]];
            }
        });
        return mapped;
    });
};
```

Comment: `const x = {...yourObject,...yourObject.Results[0]}` and afterr that `delete x.Results`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply spread the `Results` array into an [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) call.

```js
const input = { "Name": "John", "Results": [{ "Type": "DB", "Immediate_Action": "No", }, { "Another": "value" }] };

const { Results, ...refactored } = input;
Object.assign(refactored, ...Results);

console.log(refactored)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for your example:

```js
const { Results: results, ...rest } = {
  "Name": "John",
  "Results": [
    {
      "Type": "DB",
      "Immediate_Action": "No",
    }
  ]
}

const res = {...rest, ...results.reduce((prev, curr) => ({
  ...prev,
  ...curr
}), {})}

console.log(res)
```

But I don't know what you expect when the `Results` array has more than one element.

In that condition, if this code does not fill your needs, ask me to change it.

Comment: yes unfortunately the results array has more than one element. I should have mentioned that

Comment: So can you give an example of what you want to return in more than one element?

Answer (score 0):

however, it will join first Result with index 0, you can expand it

```js
const data = {
    "Name": "John",
    "Results": [
        {
            "Type": "DB",
            "Immediate_Action": "No",
        }
    ]
}

const mapOscarResults = (data) => {
for (let i in Object.keys(data)){
    if (Array.isArray(data[Object.keys(data)[i]])){
        newKey = data[Object.keys(data)[i]][0]
        data = {... data, ...newKey}
        delete data[Object.keys(data)[i]]
    }
}
return data
};

console.log(mapOscarResults(data))
```